# Single tab multiple content bootstrap 5

Tags: tabs, bootstrap-5, nav

I am working on bootstrap tabs, I am trying for the single tab with multiple content div's. I have tried by using two data-target values like data-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1".but it only works on bootstrap 4,Its not work on bootstrap 5,how is it work on bootstrap 5?

```
<body>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active show" href="#tab-1" data-bs-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1" data-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2" data-bs-target=".etab-p2, .etabi-img2" data-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3" data-bs-target=".etab-p3, .etabi-img3" data-toggle="tab">C3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-4" data-bs-target=".etab-p4, .etabi-img4" data-toggle="tab">C4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-5" data-bs-target=".etab-p5, .etabi-img5" data-toggle="tab">C5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-6" data-bs-target=".etab-p6, .etabi-img6" data-toggle="tab">C6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etab-p1">
    <p>Content 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p2">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p3">
    <p>Content 3.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p4">
    <p>Content 4.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p5">
    <p>Content 5.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etab-p6">
    <p>Content 6.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active etabi-img1">
    <p>Content 111.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img2">
    <p>Content 2222.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img3">
    <p>Content 3333.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img4">
    <p>Content 4444.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img5">
    <p>Content 5555.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade etabi-img6">
    <p>Content 6666.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<sctipt>
$('#myTab a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
  let target = $(e.target).data('bs-target');
  $(target)
    .addClass('active show')
    .siblings('.tab-pane.active')
    .removeClass('active show')
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the part of the Bootstrap 5 docs that says "[Dropped jQuery dependency and rewrote plugins to be in regular JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#javascript)"?

Therefore you need to include jQuery, and fix the markup to use `data-bs-toggle`.

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active show" href="#tab-1" data-bs-target=".etab-p1, .etabi-img1" data-bs-toggle="tab">C1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2" data-bs-target=".etab-p2, .etabi-img2" data-bs-toggle="tab">C2</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3" data-bs-target=".etab-p3, .etabi-img3" data-bs-toggle="tab">C3</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-4" data-bs-target=".etab-p4, .etabi-img4" data-bs-toggle="tab">C4</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-5" data-bs-target=".etab-p5, .etabi-img5" data-bs-toggle="tab">C5</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-6" data-bs-target=".etab-p6, .etabi-img6" data-bs-toggle="tab">C6</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://codeply.com/p/E0uoClzJZo